# Finding duration of a song

Tags: duration, sampling, quantization

This was a midterm question and I do not know how to calculate this.

A CD quality stereo song has been saved on your computer, occupying 35.28 
MBytes of storage. The CD quality mandates that we have 16-bit quantization as 
well as a uniform sampling of 44.1 KHz (samples/second). Find the duration of 
this song (Hint: 1 Bytes=8 Bits).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: follow the units.

Edit: forgot about stereo.

`(total size = bits) / (channels) / (quantization = bits/sample) / (sampling rate = samples/second)`

`= 35.28 MB / (2 channels for stereo) (16 bits/sample) / (44.1 k samples/second) = (35.28 * 8000000) / (16 * 44100)`

`= x seconds (assuming MB = 8000000 bits, not MiB)`

Comment: I hope you're not in the middle of the exam now.